# Check if all dictionaries are the same

Tags: python

I have an array of an unknown size with dictionaries in it. I'd like to check if all dictionaries are the same or not. Normally I would do either:

```
array[0] == array[1] == array[2] # with a known size
```

or:

```
len(set(array)) == 1 # if a hashable type
```

How would I do the above with an array of unknown size with dicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `all`:

```
all(a == array[0] for a in array[1:])
```